# Elasticsearch transport client spawning a large number of threads

Tags: multithreading, elasticsearch, apache-storm

From an Apache storm bolt, I am using Elasticsearch's transport client to remotely connect to an ES cluster. When I take a jstack output of the storm process, I notice that there are nearly 1000 threads with an ES stack trace like:

```
elasticsearch[Flying Tiger][transport_client_worker][T#22]{New I/O worker #269}" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f80ac3cb000 nid=0x356b runnable [0x00007f7e96b2a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x00000000d148d138> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000d148d128> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000d148c9b8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:415)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using a single instance of the ES transport client across my storm topology, which has about 18 output streams invoking the ES client to write data to the ES cluster.

Why does the ES transport client spawn so many threads ? Is there any way I can tune this ? I tried looking up ES documentation but it does not provide any internal details on the threading mechanism of the transport client nor does it give an option to tune the number of threads of the client.

Comment: 1000 sounds like a lot. Can you paste some more info in here, i.e. your Storm configuration, the command line you use to start Storm, etc

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have on the machines running storm topology?

Comment: Could you give us more details about how the ES transport client  is instantiate into your topology ?

Comment: We are looking into the large number of threads when using the Node client also.  Any update on your findings?

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar experience before. As you've mentioned, one transport client creates tens of threads including timers and so on.

What you have to check is whether there is exactly one transport client per worker process. Back in my earlier days, when I used 32 transport clients, there were more than 1 thousand threads and after I've correctly modified it to be singleton instance, number of threads decreased to less than 2 hundreds(including all other threads created in my topology)

Answer (score 0):

You can define system property: "es.processors.override" or setting "processors", based on source code of org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsExecutors. I tried this method and limit the number of worker threads successfully.

```
/**
 * Settings key to manually set the number of available processors.
 * This is used to adjust thread pools sizes etc. per node.
 */
public static final String PROCESSORS = "processors";

/** Useful for testing */
public static final String DEFAULT_SYSPROP = "es.processors.override";
```

---

Also from [limit number of thread in ThreadPool while creating TransportClient in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934404/limit-number-of-thread-in-threadpool-while-creating-transportclient-in-elasticse)

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("transport.netty.workerCount",NUM_THREADS)
                    .build();
```